# Can't access phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 12.10 64bit after installing XAMPP

Tags: 12.10, xampp, phpmyadmin

I just re-installed Ubuntu because I had been playing with a driver which I shouldn't have done.
I didn't have a backup (though I backed up the important documents etc etc) so I gotta reinstall these several applications.

So, I installed XAMPP and made so I could change stuff in htdocs.
I wanted to access a database with phpmyadmin, but I couldn't access it because it says:

---

```
Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

---

I've been searching on all over Google for solutions and absolutely none of them help.
All of them doing some minor changes in "httpd-xampp.conf" and it seems to work for them, but it just doesn't work for me.

The context I was told to change in "httpd-xampp.conf" look like this:

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory “/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin”>
AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
# New XAMPP security concept

<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))”>
Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

What can I do to make phpmyadmin work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to change any configuration file.
I assume you have installed xampp under `/opt/lampp` if so,
run this code:

```
  sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security
```

and follow the steps, then restart lampp, and you won't see the error again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just delete what is obviously the problem (that LocationMatch directive)? It's only going to be a security issue if your installation is ever exposed to a wider network.

If you running servers, even for local development, you should install a firewall - or just learn to use `ufw` and that should mitigate issues like this.

---

Edit: looking at your question, it seems that you've munged together two separate solutions to try and get this working. Unfortunately one of the posts you've copied this from has interpreted their quotes incorrectly. Note the curly-double-quotes in the second post, rather than the standard straight quotes: `"`

It's possible that if you replace them out (or grab [better copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/new-xampp-security-concept)) things might work as you expect them to.